# Connect new peer to existing Hyperledger form client side

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just setup a hyperledger network in single local system. I Already done to add new Org to an existing network using the tutorial  [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html) . I need to know something that

Q. Is possible to use hyperledger to add new peers(or run new peers) from client side..??

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible.

It has been done already, for example IBM has a full Hyperledger offering where everything is configurable via APIs. You can create channels, orgs, peers, join them etc, anything you need to build and manage a network is there.

What you could do is to build an API, which is capable of executing scripts on the machine(s) where your network is deployed. You could build such API in a language of your choosing, secured in some way and you could offer a few endpoint which do what you need to do.

1. First step in doing this is creating the script(s) which can do what you need. Make sure you have a repeatable process, write down all the commands you need, from the URL you already visited, step by step, until you go from nothing to the simplest version of the network you're happy with.
2. Create a script with all the commands you've already tested. Make sure the script can take the parameters it needs so they can be later passed via the API, like channel name, org name whatever your script creates basically.
3. Create an API with an endpoint which can called, has the required permissions and runs in the right location and can execute the script you just created. Make sure you pass the parameters you need from the API endpoint, to the script.
4. Now you can call the API from the client side.

Things to consider, the API needs to be secured somehow.

So, *Yes* it is possible and *No*, it is not an easy job. 
Is it worth doing it? Only you can answer that question to be honest.

You would also need to keep up with the changes introduced by each version increment so that's even more work to consider.

Comment: Thanks@Andrei..I have an another question. If client side call to that API. How the existing Org to approve to that new Org or peer....? I thing need to approve the above 50% of the existing Org to the new Org for joining to the network . Is it correct ..??

Comment: no, there is a process to add a new org to a channel for example. if you read the URL you shared above you'll see that the admin users of the network sign the changes to the network. Once an Org joins a channel, it can add its own peers without requiring any approvals.

Comment: But How to sing the changes by admin...If have more than one admin..How make sing all at a time...???

Comment: Any open source document is available to archive my requirement..??